# branch.io and facebook install ads attribution

Tags: facebook, flutter, branch.io

We are having trouble setting up Facebook Install Ads attribution via Branch.io. Currently, Branch.io dashboard shows we have installs via Facebook link, but Facebook ad cabinet shows 0 installs.

Our setup is

1. I've integrated branch.io for Flutter using this plugin https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_branch_sdk (Quick Links are working OK, see p.6)
2. I've setup Application on Facebook (developers.facebook.com) side and linked it to application in stores (AppStore and Google Play)
3. I've setup Facebook as Ad partner in Branch Dashboard > Partner Management, and then created Facebook link
4. I've created Ads in Facebook with aim Installs and used Branch link (all as per guides)
5. I've followed guides on Branch's docs regarding publishing - specified that we use IDFA in AppStore, all ticks as in guide, made sure we have AdSupport.framework in xCode project, added com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9+ in build.graddle, etc
6. I've exported some data from Branch Dashboard and IDFA/Android Id values were present (in Branch Dashboard > Exports > Custom Exports, as I understand, this exports Quick Links only, but still IDFA are there), this proves we are collecting these IDs.
7. Branch > Ads > Fraud dashboard is empty.
8. Branch SDK versions are 0.32.0 iOS and 5.0.1 Android

Regardless, Facebook doesn't see app Installs at all.

guides used:

1. https://help.branch.io/using-branch/docs/facebook-app-install-ads
2. https://help.branch.io/using-branch/docs/facebook-faq-and-advanced-options
3. https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/apple-app-store
4. https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/google-play
5. https://blog.branch.io/troubleshooting-facebook-install-ad-discrepancies/

What did I miss?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A Branchster Here -

Briefly explaining that SAN partners like Google AdWords/ Facebook integration is different from conventional non-SAN partners, where we send conversion data to SAN partners and they will claim the install/ Events according to their conversion logic and respond to us via API. Branch then analyses the data from all the partners and attributes the same Install/ Event based on last touch attribution logic. You will see less data on Branch dashboard as we show only attributed data for a SAN partner than the respective SAN dashboard. Please note Branch numbers is more accurate as we show the data as per cross-channel attribution.

Here are some troubleshooting you can do-

1. Please match both the [attribution windows](https://help.branch.io/using-branch/docs/facebook-faq-and-advanced-options#attribution-windows).
2. Please make sure you have synced the [timezone](https://help.branch.io/using-branch/docs/facebook-faq-and-advanced-options#timezones) on both Branch and Facebook
3. Please make sure you have [signed](https://help.branch.io/using-branch/docs/facebook-faq-and-advanced-options#can-i-get-the-data-out) the Facebook MMP or attribution data won't come.

I'll keep this post updated with general troubleshooting.

Comment: Hi Kartik, thank yuo for your reply. I see numbers on Branch end, but not in Facebook's Ad cabinet. Attribution windows are aligned. I did not sync timezones, but at the moment difference in numbers would be OK if we saw at least any in Facebook (which we don't). Regarding point 3, I thought I need to sign MMP in order to have some additional attribution data (like product purchase, etc) and installs did not require this. But OK, I've just signed MMP. I hope that will help.

Comment: And perhaps a stupid question. Should I call logEvent("INSTALL") after app first run? I thought since Facebook is SAN, install was attributed automatically. Right?

Answer (score 0):

Issue is resolved.
Recreating Ad campaigns with exactly same settings resolved the issue.
Unfortunately both Branch and Facebook support were not helpful. :(

Comment: Did you get both iOS and Android working? Running into a similar issue as yours but just on Android... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66524231/question-about-branch-io-attribution-of-facebook-app-install-ads-on-android-usin