# Question about branch.io attribution of Facebook app install ads on Android using flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, branch.io, attribution, facebook-ads

We have app install attribution working for organic links on both iOS and Android using the [flutter_branch_sdk](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_branch_sdk).

However, for Facebook app install ads, the paid attribution is only working for iOS and not for Android (we see the install events, but they don't get attributed as paid within Branch, and don't show up as installs on the FB side either). We followed the steps [here](https://help.branch.io/using-branch/docs/facebook-app-install-ads)

Also tried contacting Branch support but so far they've only pointed me to [this suggestion](https://help.branch.io/faq/docs/not-collecting-advertising-id) which didn't resolve the issue.

Wondering if anyone here has run into the same issue and has pointers?

Comment: Since this is specific to Android, I believe it might be occurring due to AAIDs, not present. Have you configured the ProGuard rules?

Comment: I am not using ProGuard